# jquery context menu disable menu items

Tags: jquery, contextmenu

For my asp.net mvc 3 application I'm using [this plugin](http://medialize.github.com/jQuery-contextMenu/). But I have a problem, I want to enable or disable some menu items, after I have created the menu, like:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        /**************************************************
         * Menu 1
         **************************************************/
        $.contextMenu({selector: '.context-menu-one', items: {
            edit: {name: "Edit", icon: "edit", callback: $.noop, accesskey:"e d i t"},
            cut: {name: "Cut", icon: "cut", callback: $.noop, accesskey:"c u t"},
            copy: {name: "Copy", icon: "copy", callback: $.noop, accesskey:"c o p y"},
            paste: {name: "Paste", icon: "paste", callback: $.noop, accesskey:"p a s t e"},
            "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete", callback: $.noop, accesskey:"d e l t"},
            sep1: "---------",
            quit: {name: "Quit", icon: "quit", callback: $.noop, accesskey:"q u i t"}
        }});

        //not working
        $('.context-menu-one').contextMenu('commands[0].disabled','true');
      });

  </script>
```

Not working, any Idea?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the plugin's [documentation](http://medialize.github.com/jQuery-contextMenu/docs.html), you can specify a function to be called in order to determine if a menu item is disabled or not.

So, you can have that function close over a local variable, and update that variable in order to enable or disable the items. Something like:

```
$(function() {
    var itemsDisabled = {};  // Enable everything initially.
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: ".context-menu-one",
        items: {
            // [...]
            cut: {
                name: "Cut",
                icon: "cut",
                callback: $.noop,
                accesskey: "c u t",
                disabled: function(key, opt) {
                    return !!itemsDisabled[key];
                }
            }
            // [...]
        }
    });

    // Disable the "Cut" menu item.
    itemsDisabled["cut"] = true;
});
```

Comment: BTW, I have found out that in order to hide an item, and not just disable it, you can use the "visible" option instead of "disabled". The definition is done the same way, except for the fact that the function under "visible" runs twice and in the first run, the parameters are not returned. So you will have to check first if the "$trigger" returns anything and then run the needed code in this function.

Comment: @TheCuBeMan it might have been nice if they mentioned that in the documentation! https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/docs/items.html#visible